# Remote control system that controls monitor 1, monitor 2 and monitor 3 with php ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to create a web based remote control system that controls monitor 1, monitor 2 and monitor 3.

Capture:
[image]

The current problem is when I press any button, let's say number 2. When button 2 is pressed, it reloads all monitors. It should only monitor 2 to change its screen.

I use php and ajax to reload the monitor page.
I give each monitor (pc) the parameter ?id={id_monitor}.
As an example:

- localhost/remote/monitor.php?id=1
- localhost/remote/monitor.php?id=2
- localhost/remote/monitor.php?id=3

And the remote button : localhost/remote/index.php.

How do I get only one of the screens to change?

This is the code monitor.php:

```
<html>
<style>
    @font-face {font-family: "Font Digital"; src: url('dist/fonts/FS Albert Pro.otf');}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0px; font-family:'Font Digital';">
    <?php $id_komputer = $_GET['id'];?>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#1a1a1a">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><p style="font-size:40px; color:#ffffff;">MONITOR <?=$id_komputer?></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkReload() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "check_reload.php?id=<?=$id_komputer?>",
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response == "standby") {
                        // NO ACTION
                    } else if (response == <?=$id_komputer?>) {
                        window.location.href = "video.php?id=<?=$id_komputer?>";
                    } else if (response == "all") {
                        window.location.href = "video.php?id=<?=$id_komputer?>";
                    } else {
                        alert("terjadi kesalahan");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        setInterval(checkReload, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've to rethink the entire logic. Either show all monitors on the same page, or search for "SPA" to get some ideas of how to update an existing page partially. Tip: stay on the current page, don't navigate to a new page.

Comment: Where is the code for those buttons, and what exactly do they send to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem.

The problem is that the check_reload.php file incorrectly returns the required data.

Thank you.